# How to bind data to the form in symfony

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have a variable that need to be bind into a form in symfony, how can I bind data from action file to form?

The Action File
 $this->unitCost = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('unit_cost');
         $value_lists = ($this->unitCost);

```
    foreach($value_lists as $values)
        {
        echo $values['unit_cost'];
        }
    $form = new MyForm(); $form->bind(array('unit_cost' => $values['unit_cost']));
     //print_r($value_lists);
```

Form
public function configure() {

```
    $cost_range[''] = '-- Please select --';
    for ($i = 0; ($i <= 100); $i++) {
        $cost_range[$i] = $i;
    }

    $this->setWidgets(array(
        'user_id' => new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'Person', 'add_empty' => '-- Please select --'), array('onchange' => 'filerUnitCostByName()', 'id' => 'user_id')),
        'unit_cost' => new sfWidgetFormSelect(array('choices' => $cost_range), array('id'=>'unit_cost')),
    ));
```

How can I display the bind value through the number drop down through the Form
I am taking data from a dropdown and putting in to a session, and then retrieve the data in the action. I want to set the selected variable in a dropdown created in the form created in with widget. as u can see in the widget area. I want to add the value as default value.

Comment: Please write down more precisely what is your purpose, what do you want to achieve. I'm not sure your problem is about binding the form.

Comment: What the difference with the other question you askted [How to bind a array with a single data to a form using the Action file in Symfony](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145127/how-to-bind-a-array-with-a-single-data-to-a-form-using-the-action-file-in-symfon) ?

Answer (score 2):

For bind variables from your POST request, you can do this :

```
$form = new MyForm();
$form->bind($request->getParameter($form->getName()), $request->getFiles($form->getName()));
```

If you want bind one extra variable, you can do this :

```
$form = new MyForm();
$form->bind(array_merge($request->getParameter($form->getName()), array('foo' => $foo)), $request->getFiles($form->getName()));
```

Edit : Without POST variables, you can do :

```
$form = new MyForm();
$form->bind(array('foo' => $foo));
```

Comment: Will it will be possible to add he bind without the post request. I want the details just to be viewed in the form, as a item in a dropdown.

Comment: Yeah sure : $form = new MyForm();
$form->bind(array('foo' => $foo));